# how to add null values wherever there is a nan value using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

I am trying to read the csv file through java as `attributes[17]` here have some nan values so when i read those **NaN** values i want those rows to also have **NULL** values how to do that.   As i am adding 0 whenever it has the exception of **Nan** so i wanted to add **NULL** values in such case.How to do that

```
 try
    {
        double vb=Double.parseDouble(attributes[17]);

        invoice_id=(long) vb;
        invoice_no.add(invoice_id);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
    //e.printStackTrace();
        long b=0;
        invoice_no.add(b);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        long b=0;
        invoice_no.add(b);
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of variable `attributes`? I suggest you put more code in the question to make people understand the situation.

Comment: attributes is a string type that have NaN values too

Answer (score 0):

we need to use this

```
pstmt.setNull(17,java.sql.Types.LONGNVARCHAR);
```

here **pstmt** is the **PreparedStatement**